# Packaging Images in py2exe?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, py2exe

I am having trouble packaging my python Tkinter GUI file into a .exe executable file with py2exe. When I finish building the application through the command prompt and open the .exe application that was converted, I get the error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
   File "Gui.py", line 15, in <module>
   File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1624, in wm_iconbitmap
  _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "TSicon.ico" not defined
```

How do I get py2exe to be able to function with the images that I put into my Tkinter Python file and successfully convert my python file to .exe executable.

Comment: That gets me wondering, can a compiled -to exe- python script access outside files like an uncompiled one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is that the `TSicon.ico` is not copied to the same folder where the `.exe` file resides. Assume that the python file and `TSicon.ico` are in the same folder. Then, you `setup.py` should look like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

data_files = [('', [r'TSicon.ico'])]

setup(
windows =['tk_with_image.py'],
data_files = data_files,
options={
         }
)
```

Now the `.exe` file and the `TSicon.ico`  will be in the same folder (`dist`), and everything should work.